# QTP: Get list of all links in an E-mail

Tags: parsing, automated-tests, qtp, extract

I'm "developing" a test plan in Mercury/HP QuickTest Pro 9.1, in which I must extract a list of all links in an E-mail and perform logic against each of them.

In this case, I am using Webmail, so the message will appear as a web page; though I hope to use Outlook later to replicate a more realistic UX.

I am a Developer, not a Tester. Can anyone provide me with some "code" that will perform this extraction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call the `ChildObjects` method to return a collection of child objects of a given type. For example, to get a list of all the Link objects on the Google home page:

```
set oDesc = Description.Create()
oDesc("micclass").Value = "Link"
set links = Browser("title:=Google").Page("title:=Google").ChildObjects(oDesc)
For i = 0 To links.Count-1
    reporter.ReportEvent micInfo, links(i).GetROProperty("text"), ""
Next
```

So you just need to identify the web element that contains the body of the email and use that as the parent for the search.

Answer (score 1):

If you end up going the Outlook route, you can use the Outlook API to do it, without having to use QTP's GUI code.

```
sServer = "your.server.address.here" '"your.server.address.here"
sMailbox = "JoeSmith" '"mailboxName"

' build the ProfileInfo string
sProfileInfo = sServer & vbLf & sMailbox

' create your session and log on    
Set oSession = CreateObject("MAPI.Session")
oSession.Logon "", "", False, True, 0, True, sProfileInfo

' create your Inbox object and get the messages collection
Set oInbox = oSession.Inbox
Set oMessageColl = oInbox.Messages

' get the first message in the collection
Set oMessage = oMessageColl.GetFirst

If oMessage Is Nothing Then
   MsgBox "No messages found"
Else
   ' loop through inbox
   Do
     With oMessage
        ' message data:
        Debug.Print .Subject & vbCrLf & .TimeReceived & vbCrLf & .Text
        ' this triggers the clever Outlook security dialog:
        'Debug.Print .Sender(1) & vbCrLf & .Recipients(1)
        Debug.Print
     End With

     Set oMessage = oMessageColl.GetNext
   Loop Until oMessage Is Nothing
End If

'Logoff your session and cleanup
oSession.Logoff

Set oMessage = Nothing
Set oMessageColl = Nothing
Set oInbox = Nothing
Set oSession = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'write qtp script to display names of links in  jkcwebsite page
Option explicit
Dim bro,url,n,desc,childs,i
bro="c:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE"
url="http://ieg.gov.in/"
invokeapplication bro&" "&url
'create description for link type
Set desc=description.Create
desc ("micclass").value="link"
'get all links in jkc page
Set childs=browser("title:=Jawahar Knowledge Center").Page("title:=Jawahar Knowledge Center").ChildObjects(desc)
For i=0 to childs.count-1 step 1
    n=childs(i).getroproperty("name")
    print n
Next
n=childs.count
browser("title:=Jawahar Knowledge Center").Close
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Rather than only post a block of code, please explain why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not an answer.